# jquery call to a vb.net function and use response to populate a textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am using this code:

```
$("#dropdownPaper").change(function () {
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "NomexLine500A.aspx/CalcBlockCode",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#textBlockCode").text(data.d)
                    },
                    error: function (result) { }
                });
            });
```

to respond to a dropdownlist change to run a function in the codebehind file for the aspx page.

Here is the function in the code behind:

```
Protected Function CalcBlockCode() As String
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim paper As New DropDownList
    Dim cylinder As New DropDownList
    'Dim blockcode As New TextBox

    paper = FormView1.FindControl("dropdownPaperItem")
    cylinder = FormView1.FindControl("dropdownCylinderNumber")
    'blockcode = CType(FormView1.FindControl("textBlockCode"), TextBox)

    If paper.Text = "" Or paper.Text = "None" Then
        CalcBlockCode = "NA"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If cylinder.Text = "" Or cylinder.Text = "None" Then
        CalcBlockCode = "NA"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim strCellSizeCode As String
    Dim intMil As Decimal
    Dim strCylinderID As String

    strCellSizeCode = DLookup("CellSizeCode", "Cylinders", "CYLINDERS = '" & cylinder.Text & "'")
    intMil = DLookup("Mil", "PaperPart", "ITEM_NBR = '" & paper.Text & "'")
    strCylinderID = DLookup("CylinderID", "Cylinders", "CYLINDERS = '" & cylinder.Text & "'")

    strReturn = Convert.ToInt32(intMil * 10) & strCellSizeCode & strCylinderID

    CalcBlockCode = strReturn
End Function
```

In the Firefox web tools I dont see any evidence that the jquery function is running. If it does run, i am not getting a return value. Am I referencing the right url for the ajax call to get the function from the code behind?

Comment: Please use `Return` instead of assigning to the implicit function variable and writing `Exit Function`. And there’s no reason to even have `strReturn`…

Comment: In c#, the method you want to call needs to be `public static` and be decorated with the `WebMethod` attribute. I assume your code needs the equivalent. Also, since the method needs to be `static`, I think you need to pass relevant values with the ajax call instead of accessing controls from the method.

Comment: And `OrElse` instead of `Or`. And that really looks like SQL injection you have there.

Comment: Also, remove the quotes around the data object.  It should be `data: {}`

Answer (score 1):

In your codebehind first:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
```

then put this on top of your function and make your function public shared

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function CalcBlockCode() As String
'....
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

As per @JsonP's comment to your answer, you will need to pass in your values to the ajax call as:

```
$.ajax({
//...
data: {'paper': $('yourdropdown').val(), 'cylinder':$('yourotherdropdown')} // notice the removal of quotes from around {} as per the comment from @Archer
//...
})
```